# CF buildpack modification and hooks

Tags: cloud-foundry

I read about CF buildpack's like java buildpack but I dont find any documentation which describe where I can modify buildpack e.g. provide some env, ( I know that I can do it from application with set-env but im not talking about it...) 
My question are:

1. where I can modify buildpack (some built-in hooks) without the need to fork it...
2. where I can provide env to it? droplet

I refer to the open source official CF buildpacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to do. If you want to modify the staging (i.e., compilation) step of the buildpack, as far as I'm aware that's not currently possible. (There was [some discussion on the CF mailing list](http://cf-dev.70369.x6.nabble.com/cf-dev-Staging-and-Runtime-Hooks-Feature-Narrative-td4532.html) a while ago with a proposal to add such a feature, but it seems like the staging-time hook idea was nixed).

If you want to run a hook after your droplet has been compiled, but before your app is started, you can put custom code in `.profile` at the root of your project directory. See this page for documentation of `.profile`: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html#profile

Comment: I think the PHP buildpack is the only exception.  It has hooks you can use at staging, so you don't need to fork to add behavior.  All other buildpacks, you would basically fork and add your staging customizations.